Order of c++ template arguments affecting compilation
I just encountered a new compilation error in my code after a visual studio update. I have stripped my code down to what I think is a minimal example. I have two templated functions both called pow - the first takes two parameters of any type and calls std::pow with them. The second uses a concept to override the first template such that if the second parameter matches the concept it gets called instead.
In my code, I for some reason had the two template parameters in the opposite order to how they appeared in the parameter list. This used to compile, but recently stopped compiling with the error 'pow': ambiguous call to overloaded function. However, if I swap the order of the template parameters to match the function parameters it compiles fine.
Why would this compile one way and not the other?
Here is the minimal example
#include <cmath>
template<class T, class U>
double pow(const T& base, const U& power)
{
    return std::pow(base, power);
}

template<class T>
concept HasValue =
    requires(std::remove_cvref_t < T > t)
{
    t.value;
};


//this causes an ambiguous call to overloaded function compilation error
template<HasValue T, class U>
double pow(const U& s, const T& a)
{
    return std::pow(s, a.value);
}

//this works with no compilation error
//template<class U, HasValue T>
//double pow(const U& s, const T& a)
//{
//  return std::pow(s, a.value);
//}

class MyClass
{
public:
    double value;
};

int main()
{
    MyClass myClass;
    myClass.value = 2.0;
    pow(10.0, myClass);
}


Unrelated: As a general rule, don't name your functions the same as standard library functions. Or atleast put them in your own namespace instead of the global namespace.

The reason for the caution that @user12002570 gives is that implementations are allowed to put std function in the global namespace. That's usually not an issue with the C++ portion of the standard library, but the functions inherited form C tend to e defined in the global namespace, and implementations hoist them into std with using declarations. So putting funct5ions with the same names into got global namespace can lead to conflicts.

Once upon a time I named a variable strlen because it contained the length of a string. After much fuss and frustration with a completely bizarre series of compiler errors, I found that the strlen library function was not a function at all and was instead a macro. Since the normal scoping rules that would have allowed me to use my variable strlien  in a scope that didn't also need to use the function strlen do not apply to macros, I had a very bad day. Lesson learned: Don't resuse library function names.

Indeed, my actual code has these functions in a namespace, however this was removed as part of creating a minimal reproducible example.

I think the overload resolution making more constrained better than less constrained only works if the order of argument deduction is the same. When you swapped the template types, you've got two overloads neither one is better than the other. Somebody will find the corresponding section of the Standard.

The partial ordering of function templates is defined in section 13.7.7.3 of the Standard. Quoting (from N4981) paragraph 2:

Partial ordering selects which of two function templates is more
specialized than the other by transforming each template in turn (see
next paragraph) and performing template argument deduction using the
function type. The deduction process determines whether one of the
templates is more specialized than the other. If so, the more
specialized template is the one chosen by the partial ordering
process. If both deductions succeed, the partial ordering selects the
more constrained template (if one exists) as determined below.

The next paragraphs go into details of transformations applied to template parameters and how unique type is synthesized.
Paragraph 6 describes the ordering of transformed templates. The case when you have
template<class T, class U>
double pow(const T& base, const U& power);
template<class U, HasValue T>
double pow(const U& s, const T& a)

falls through to 6.4

(6.4) — Otherwise, if one template is more constrained than the other
(13.5.5), the more constrained template is more specialized than the
other.

The case when you have a reversed order of template types
template<class T, class U>
double pow(const T& base, const U& power);
template<HasValue T, class U>
double pow(const U& s, const T& a);

goes to reversed order rules 6.2 and lands in 6.2.2

(6.2.2) — Otherwise, if the corresponding template-parameters of the
template-parameter-lists are not equivalent (13.7.7.2) or if the
function parameters that positionally correspond between the two
templates are not of the same type, neither template is more
specialized than the other.

and since neither template is more specialized than the other it results in ambiguity error emitted by compilers.
